# How to insert formatted text in mysql db?

Tags: javascript, mysql, html, quill

I am using quill as to write rich text and able to read the data from div.But while inserting into there is no error thrown by DB or code, but data is not getting into the DB.Can someone please help me to resolve the issue.

```js
function addComment() {
  var quill = new Quill('#comment');
  var cc =  quill.getContents();
  var reqBody = {
    "comment": cc
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
    url: "addcomment",
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR : ", e);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="standalone-container">
          <div id="toolbar-container">
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <select class="ql-font"></select>
              <select class="ql-size"></select>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-bold"></button>
              <button class="ql-italic"></button>
              <button class="ql-underline"></button>
              <button class="ql-strike"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <select class="ql-color"></select>
              <select class="ql-background"></select>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
              <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
              <button class="ql-header" value="2"></button>
              <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
              <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
              <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
              <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
              <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl"></button>
              <select class="ql-align"></select>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-link"></button>
              <button class="ql-image"></button>
              <button class="ql-video"></button>
              <button class="ql-formula"></button>
            </span>
            <span class="ql-formats">
              <button class="ql-clean"></button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="min-height:50px;" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 pull-right" style="top:5px;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" onclick="addComment()">Add</button>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Please find the above code for problem understanding.When I call this function no data inserted into the database.

Comment: You question is unclear. Okay, it's not working, but how we guess where's the problem? Show us some code, or better, create a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EliasSoares I have added the code.Sorry for incomplete information.Let me know if you need any other information on this.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to insert the HTML in DB using following code:

var quill = new Quill('#comment');
var cc =  quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML;

Now cc will hold the input content that can be inserted into DB.